# Ansible : display variable in jinja template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a playbook in order to run a shell command to count the number of updates.

I would like to display this result in a file but this result is false.

My playbook :

```yaml
- name: Listing packages
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Count number of updates
      shell: yum check-update | wc -l
      register: nbupdates

    - name: Display number of updates
      debug:
        var: nbupdates.stdout_lines

    - name: output to html file
      template:
        src: ./jinja/src/tpl_dashboard_update.j2
        dest: ./jinja/dst/dashboard_update.html
        force: yes
      delegate_to: localhost
```

My jinja template is this one:

```
{% for host in vars['play_hosts'] %}
{{ host | upper }} : we have {{ nbupdates.stdout_lines[0] }} updates
{% endfor %}
```

When I run the playbook, I always have the same number of updates for each server like if the loop is not working.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See [hostvars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables). Try [extract](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) filter, e.g. ``{{ ansible_play_hosts|map('extract', hostvars, ['nbupdates', 'stdout'] }}``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your template.

- `vars` is an undocumented internal variable with undesirable behaviour and should not be used.
- Your use of `vars` is completely unnecessary, so you can just remove it instead of replacing it with the [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html).
- `play_hosts` is [deprecated](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) and should not be used.
- Your task should use [`run_once`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation-and-parallel-execution) so that it only runs once, instead of once for each server.
- You should [use `hostvars` to access information about other hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables) instead of always using the value for the current host.

```yaml
    - name: output to html file
      template:
        src: ./jinja/src/tpl_dashboard_update.j2
        dest: ./jinja/dst/dashboard_update.html
        force: yes
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

```
{% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
{{ host | upper }} : we have {{ hostvars[host].nbupdates.stdout_lines.0 }} updates
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank your for your answer. I'm using vars to display result

Comment: I don't understand what your comment is supposed to mean.

Comment: When I said "vars is an undocumented internal variable" I was referring to the use, in your template, of `vars['play_hosts']`. Your debug task does not contain the string `vars` anywhere in it.